Post curl request in Deployment kind lifecyclehook in deployment yaml file with Openshift upgrade to 4.14
As by OpenShift 4.14, DeploymentConfig is getting deprecated and we need to use kind:Deployment
Previous we use something like this for sending notification for deployment:
kind: DeploymentConfig metadata: xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx name: xxxxxx namespace: xxxxxxxx spec: replicas: 1 selector: name: xxxxxxxxxxx strategy: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx rollingParams: post: failurePolicy: Ignore execNewPod: containerName: xxxxxxxxx command: - /bin/sh - '-c' - |- curl -X POST https://postnotification-url.abcd.com/post \ -H "Accept:application/json" \ -H "Content-Type:application/json" \ -d \ '{ "sid": "123" }' 
, I need somthing similiar for Deployment as well

Tried adding with command attribute
image: container-image command: ["/bin/sh"] args: ["-c", "curl -X POST https://abcd/post {}]
Curl getting executed but application goes to crashloop
Also tried adding with lifecycle attribute
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent lifecycle: postStart: exec: command: - /bin/sh - -c - > curl -X POST https://abcd.com/post \ -H "Accept:application/json" \ -H "Content-Type:application/json" \ -d '{ "sid": "1234" }'
Some one please help with this


I had the same problem switching from deploymentConfig to deployment, but I solved this problem by managing the deployment with a Helm Chart and creating a job configured with a post-install hook. It is also very convenient if you decide to adopt ArgoCD in the future because it recognises Helm hooks.
